# Does the Stone of Jordan have any special properties or significance in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

When Diablo 2 was first released, there was a sequence you had to go through in order to get the unique rings.  In order to get the Stone of Jordan, you needed to first get the Manald Heal and Nagelrings.

[All](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/nagelring) [three](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/manald-heal) [rings](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stone-of-jordan) are back in Diablo 3 (plus a bunch more).

The Stone of Jordan (SoJ) became a unit of currency throughout Diablo 2, to the point where Blizzard created a special event that could be triggered by selling enough SoJ's.

Does the [Stone of Jordan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stone-of-jordan) in Diablo 3 have any special properties or significance that sets aside from other items in the game?

Comment: At this point I don't believe it is known. It may take some time after release for reliable information to coalesce.

Comment: I see you edited this, but I'm unsure what you are now asking. If you are asking questions to participate in the contest, please try to ask "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face," per the FAQ.

Comment: @Wikwocket The edits are in response to concerns raised in [chat]. The question ("Does the SoJ in D3 have any special properties or significance like it did in D2?") is both practical and answerable, based upon the specific history of the SoJ in D2.

Comment: To get a SoJ in D2, you didn't need to have the other rings. But because of the way the unique rings dropped, the chance of getting a SoJ was higher or 100% if it was a unique ring. Simplified if a unique ring dropped, it would never be the same as the unique rings people had currently in the game. So if you had alle the other unique rings it was guaranteed to be a SoJ.

Comment: This garantee of identifying a unique ring as a SoJ when equiping other two unique rings has been fixes a long time ago.
You could easily drop a dwarf star ring or a ravenfrost before droping a soj, even if you had both geared on you already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not any that is known at this time.

Comment: To downvoter: Sorry, but there isn't much more you can say to prove a negative.

Answer (score 3):

With the expansion Reaper of Souls. [Stone of Jordan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stone-of-jordan) has a guaranteed chance to roll

> Increases damage against elites by 25–30%
>
> ---
>
> One of 7 Magic Properties (varies)
>
> ```
> Physical skills deal 15–20% more damage.
>
> Poison skills deal 15–20% more damage.
>
> Lightning skills deal 15–20% more damage.
>
> Cold skills deal 15–20% more damage.
>
> Fire skills deal 15–20% more damage.
>
> Arcane skills deal 15–20% more damage.
>
> Holy skills deal 15–20% more damage.
> ```

This somewhat sets it apart from other rings. Other than that, it is just a ring.

Comment: It's one of the few legendary rings that can roll +elemental damage, I believe.  That, plus this extra damage to elites, makes it insanely awesome.

Comment: yep, a good soj can double your effective dps vs elites and bosses

Comment: Because of these stats, I'm pretty sure it has the potential (rolls willing) to be the single best ring in the game damage wise. Top rolls would be something like : `30% Elite damage, 20% element damage, 6% crit chance(?), 50% crit damage, 500(?) Primary stat`. No other ring could give you that much damage.

Comment: you can only have 4 primary stats. And all those you listed are primary. Still, it is a pretty great ring with just 4 of those. Especially elite damage, element damage, crit damage and primary stat. You can probably get the crit chance somewhere else.